# Crystal Reports Dynamically Grouping by Date

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm relatively new to Crystal Reports and it seems like this should be easy, but I haven't been able to figure it out after a lot of googling.  I'm working on a report in Crystal Reports XI that will show total hours logged by support staff for a date range and show sub totals by week, month, or both depending on the user input.  My report is currently arranged as follows:

```
Group 1 Header - Support Staff Member 
  Group 2 Header - Ticket Closed Date with section printed monthly
    Group 3 Header - Ticket Closed Date with section printed weekly
      Group 4 Header - Ticket Category
      Group 4 Footer - Sum of time logged in each category for the week
    Group 3 Footer - Sum of time logged in all categories for the week   
  Group 2 Footer - Sum of time logged in all categories for the month
Group 1 Footer - Sum of all time logged
```

My original idea was just to suppress the header and footer for groups 2 and 3 when they weren't needed, but if I manually do that it still prints the records by week and month.  Is there a way to not have the grouping at all unless the parameter says to show those totals?  Or if that isn't an option, how would I use the parameter to change whether the group prints records weekly or monthly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be create a string parameter 'option' with values weekly and monthly.

Now create a formula grouping.

```
If ?parameter='weekly'
Then //your weekly code here

Else if ?parameter='monthly'
Then //your monthly code
```

Now use this formula in grouping instead of multiple groups.

Now when user selects option your grouping will change dynamically.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the response @Siva.  You pointed me in the right direction and I found this [site](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports/blog/2011/07/21/parameterized-date-group-intervals-in-crystal-reports) to help with the weekly/monthly code